# Hide FrameLayout inside AppBarLayout

Tags: android

im trying to hide a FrameLayout by code inside an AppBarLayout using the below code but its not working. What is the correct code to Grab the Frame inside the AppBarLayout. 
Thanks

**API used 23**

**Code tried**

```
FrameLayout search = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
           search.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Layout app_bar_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.place_point.placepoint.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="-56dp"
            android:background="#795548">


        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```
search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Check [docs for `setSystemUiVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)) it's for things like Full Screen mode.